# PrimeFaces 3.3.1 calendar disable future dates, in international application

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am writing a JSF 2.0 Mojarra application using Primefaces 3.3.1 on Tomcat 6.  Using the PrimeFaces `<p:calendar>` component, I need to disable future dates.  I realize that I must set the maxdate attribute to the current date.  However, I am not sure what the easiest way is to accomplish this.

I realize that I could create a Managed Bean of `java.util.Date`, but this is an international application, and I need to account for the location of the user.  If the user is on the other side of the world, the server date could be incorrect for him.

**So, what is the easiest way to retrieve the current date at the user's location, and set the `<p:calendar>` maxdate attribute equal to that value?**  A completely client-side solution would be ideal, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the client system date.

`<p:calendar>` calendar is an jquery-ui widget, you can have client acess on it by defining widgetVar and set the maxdate using javascript.

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="myCalendar" />
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        myCalendar.jqEl.datepicker("option", "maxDate", +0);//set maxDate to today
     });     
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, that is awesome.  I will try it out.  Sorry if this is a silly question, but does the format of the third parameter have any consequence?  That is, what if I used "dd-MMM-yy"?  Thanks again!

Comment: Should it match the format of my `pattern` attribute?  That is currently "dd-MMM-yy", which is working, although I am now seeing in the jQuery documentation that "MM" is the format for month name long.  Am I using an improper format?

Comment: p:calendar has maxDate as well that does this for you.

Comment: @CagatayCivici , thanks for commenting. I love PrimeFaces! Are you saying that there is an alternative to the jQuery solution? I am using maxDate, but I was unsure how to best pull the client's current date.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro I cannot get the jQuery solution to work.  I have tried several variations, including removing my `pattern` attribute in case it was conflicting somehow.  I have been reading through the documentation, but cannot figure it out.  This is a sample of what I am currently trying:  `<p:calendar id="dateName" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" required="true" value="#{someBean.dateProperty}" 
navigator="true" widgetVar="dateName"/><script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){dateName.jqEl.datepicker("option", "maxDate", "dd-M-yy");});</script>`

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro, after reading through the jQuery documentation a bit more, I was able to get your answer to work with a slight modification.  I replaced `("option", "maxDate", "yy-mm-dd")`, with `("option", "maxDate", +0)`.  I am going to make this minor change to your answer and mark it correct.  Thanks!  This was a great solution.

Answer (score 5):

As primefaces-chief **Cagatay Civici** already stated out you can use  `p:calendar` `maxDate` for that reason. As I dont what to mix up my facelets with JS, here is the way I did it:

faclet:

```
<p:calendar maxdate="#{bean.today}" />
```

bean:

```
public Date getToday() {
        return new Date();
    }
```

So no future to be selectable.

Comment: As stated in my question, that does not solve the problem, because it returns the server date, not the local date of the user.  The marked answer is correct.

Comment: Oops, I somehow missed that :(

Comment: user can type previous date. how to restrict him from writing previous date.

Comment: user can type previous date. how to restrict him from writing previous date

Answer (score 0):

We can also use faces-config.xml to define currentDate bean

```
enter code here
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>currentDate</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Then use it in .xhtml

```
<p:calendar maxdate="#{currentDate}" />
```

Answer (score -2):

its more simple than that 
it disable all the past dates until the current day

Comment: Apart from probably filtering out the wrong dates, how would the OP achieve this. Could he do so on the client side?